# R, where is data set DHHS

Tags: r, dataset

The DHHS Collaboration Network (DHHS) contains network data from a study of the
relationships among 54 tobacco control experts working in 11 different agencies
in the Department of Health and Human Services in 2005.

I googled it but has no clue. Where can I find this data set and use it in R? Thank you.

When I put it in R:

```
data(DHHS)
```

it shows:

```
data set ‘DHHS’ not found
```

Comment: Close voters: this question is not asking for a recommendation. It's asking for directions.

Comment: @HongOoi That falls in the same category: asking us to find an off-site resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start installing the `UserNetR` package

```
install_github("DougLuke/UserNetR")
```

Then

```
library(UserNetR)
data(DHHS)
plot(DHHS)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! this helps other people too!